# How can I make YouTube ads show up when embedding YouTube into Android app

Tags: android, youtube

For some reason the YouTube ads don't get shown when a person is watching the YouTube videos when they are embedded inside an app.

Would anyone know if there is a workaround for this? Or how to make it possible? Or will it always be impossible to show YouTube ads this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the owners of the video have requested ad's and allowed embedding, the ad's will play. The owner of the content is who get's paid.

If you own the content, you can mark your content for ad's and allow embedding, and you'll get paid.

further information:
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/132596?hl=en

also you can have more control on the playing videos using `YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener` https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener